# variable not passing correct value. listAdd ends up being "[object text] [object text]" javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm trying to get my addItem to read the data from another one and then write it back to the dom. It all works fine with one variable at a time, but not when I try and concat or append them together. 
After the append or concat function the variable listAdd reads as "[object text] [object text]" in firebug. when it should just read as a one value.

```
// calculates price
function calcPrice() {
  var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
  var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;           
  var total = price * quantity;
  return total;
};

// adds item to dom
document.getElementById("add").onclick = function addItem(){
  var newItem = document.getElementById("item").value;
  var li=document.createElement("li");            
  var item = document.createTextNode(newItem);
  var total = document.createTextNode(calcPrice());
  var listAdd = item + total;
  li.append(listAdd);
  $("receipt").appendChild(li);
};

// removes last li element from ul
document.getElementById("remove").onclick = function removeItem(){
  $("li:last-child").remove();
};
```

Comment: why oh why are you mixing jQuery and non-jQuery DOM manipulation?

Comment: I hadn't cleaned it up after I started to implement the jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
var item = document.createTextNode(newItem);
var total = document.createTextNode(calcPrice());
var listAdd = item + total;
```

You're adding together two objects. When you convert an object to a string, you typically get something like `"[Object object]"`. You're performing this conversion on both objects, and concatenating the resulting strings.

You've tagged this question with jQuery, and actually *used* jQuery for parts of it. If you want to use jQuery, then **use jQuery**:

```
$('#add').click(function () {
  var newItem = $('#item').value();
  var li = $('<li/>');
  li.text(newItem + calcPrice());
  $("receipt").append(li);
});
```

Comment: Ok, it still isn't writing to the dom.

http://jsfiddle.net/Gilgamesh415/vTgrj/4/

Answer (score -1):

value of input box is always returned as type string, to perform arithmetic operations you must cast it to preper number so that you can perform

Try this

```
function calcPrice() {
var price = parseInt(document.getElementById("price").value,10);
var quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById("quantity").value,10);           
var total = price * quantity;
return total;
};
```

and change

```
var newItem = parseInt(document.getElementById("item").value,10);
```

Comment: Always add a radix when using parseInt, parseInt(document.getElementById("item").value , 10);

Comment: var newItem is a string not a number.

Comment: You are wrong. `"5" * "9"` gives 45. You do *not* have to "cast" (it's not casting) strings to integers before multiplying them.